# Grub: Fixing Partitions So Ubuntu Is Bootable

Tags: 10.04, partitioning, grub2

I have messed up my partitions so now grub doesn't work correctly, and I end up with a `grub>` prompt.   I used the LiveCD to open up `gparted`, and found the following: [image: image from gparted running off of the livecd]

Can someone help me with fixing up the partitions or let me know how to fix them up so that I can boot my netbook with Ubuntu 10.04?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu within Windows (using wubi)?

Answer (score 2):

(NOTE: I edited the question, so I'm going to answer based off my edits)

I believe that when you were working with the partitions, you ended up formatting the 10.04 partition (which should be ext4) as an NTFS partition, because as you can see in gparted, everything is showing up as NTFS.

You could of course reinstall Ubuntu 10.04, but you'd  need to use the advanced parition editor to make sure you correctly configure the partitions that you want Ubuntu to use.